# Does my motherboard supports M2 SSD?

Tags: ssd

My mother board is Gigabyte p75-d3 , so does it supports NVME M2 SSD? And how do I know that my motherboard supports M2 SSD from its specifications ?

Comment: If you look at the Storage Interface section of your specs it only supports msata, not M.2>>>>>https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-P75-D3-rev-10/sp#sp

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Kinda hard on a new member are you?

Comment: This member has [plenty of reputation on other SE's](https://stackexchange.com/users/10534284/john-adams?tab=accounts) and I would expect that they would know by now that a tiny bit of research is expected.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Thanks for the reply . But actually I have done a lot of research but unfortunately I didn't understand .

Comment: @Moab Thank you for ur help .

Comment: Great to hear that you've done a lot of research. However, would you be so kind to show that in your question as well? I have no other way of telling what you're thinking besides the content of the question. Something like: "I looked at the specifications (link to specs), saw that it supports MSATA, but couldn't understand from the MSATA wiki (link to wiki) if that also means M2 is supported" would be a very helpful addition.

Comment: Msata and M.2 are not interchangeable, they have different slot types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears not. Every specification that I've seen for the [GA-P75-D3](https://www.gigabyte.com/uk/Motherboard/GA-P75-D3-rev-10) lists an mSATA slot and makes no mention of anywhere else that you could put an SSD. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) can tell you, M.2 slots are typically seen as replacements to mSATA slots. It's quite unlikely that the manufacture would provide both but not advertise this fact, so I must conclude that **you do not have support for M.2**.